# How can I pull out the North, East, South, and West values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, mongodb

```
const data = [
  {
    mapview_id: [
      {
        west: 11.5,
        south: 55.75,
        east: 12,
        north: 56,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I am not sure why I am having issues with this. Each time I try to get the data, I end up creating another array and nest the data even further.

Comment: What format/shape do you want the data in?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

I have stored them into an array since I was unsure how you want it structured.

```
     let directions = [
     {
        mapview_id: [
          {
            west: 11.5,
            south: 55.75,
            east: 12,
            north: 56,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    directions.forEach(x =>{
        Object.values(x).forEach(y =>{
            console.log(Object.values(y[0]))
        })
    })
```

EDIT:  Your original structure was incomplete and since I was unsure, I took the initiative and closed it off with a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

assuming there are multiple `ids`, you can loop over it

```js
const obj =[ {
    mapview_id: [
      {
        west: 11.5,
        south: 55.75,
        east: 12,
        north: 56,
      },
    ]
  } ]

for (element of obj[0]["mapview_id"]) {
    console.log(Object.values(element))
}
```

Comment: It appeared to be encapsulated in an array, considering he was missing an initial bracket.

Answer (score 0):

you can samply do it using destructuring

```
 let directions = [
 {
    mapview_id: [
      {
        west: 11.5,
        south: 55.75,
        east: 12,
        north: 56,
      },
    ],
  },
];

let {west, south, east,north} = directions[0]['mapview_id'][0];
console.log(west, south, east,north)
// 11.5 55.75 12 56,
```

Comment: If you're going to desctructure... `const [{ mapview_id: [{ north, south, east, west }] }] = directions;`

Comment: completely opinionated like a glass half full and half empty.